# Trying to check probabilities of a slot machine using R

Tags: r

I have an excel sheet that looks like:

```
BAR1    BAR1    BAR2    5   6   40  
BLANK   BLANK   BLANK   4   10  9  
Bar1    SEV BAR1    5   50  40  
BLANK   BLANK   BLANK   3   61  9  
BAR2X   BAR1    BAR2    30  51  23  
BLANK   BLANK   BLANK   3   61  31
```

I want to create a table that has all of the symbols in the left most column, with the appropriate number of times that symbol showed up. ie

```
Bar1    10(5+5)    57(51+6)   40(40)  
Blank   10         132        49  
.....
```

I have been doing my best to research this but I assume you guys will quickly come up with a very elegant solution to get me started. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you are getting the values in the second table from that in the first. For example, you have `80(40+40)` as the last column in the Bar1 row, but I don't see two 40's associating with Bar1 in the first table.

Comment: Could you please `dput` some of the data?

Comment: I edited my calculations. I mistakenly added the wrong numbers. I'm sure that your original thinking was correct. I will try the dput thing a littler later in the day.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are essentially trying to summarize the values grouped by corresponding columns, you can subset your data frame into three data frames, do the summary and then merge them back. So something like this should work:

```
cols = list(c(1,4), c(2,5), c(3,6))
aggList <- lapply(cols, function(i) 
                  aggregate(x = df[i][[2]], by = list(tolower(df[i][[1]])), sum))

Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "Group.1"), aggList)
  Group.1 x.x x.y  x
1    bar1  10  57 40
2   blank  10 132 49
```